# Docker php-apache:73 image install newer version of msmtp

Tags: php, docker

For docker php 7.3 offical image, when I install msmtp via `apt get install msmtp` I get version msmtp-1.8.11. How can I get a newer version via package manager or other method? This version is 2 years old (NOTE I am doing apt get upgrade and apt-get update before installing)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here, in debian you can get only 1.8.11 via package manager: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=msmtp

You can get the newer releases from the official page or get the source code from git: https://marlam.de/msmtp/download/